# How to disable the face overlay in the UV editor?

Tags: interface, uv

Is it possible to disable the transparent face overlay in the *UV editor*?

Since the opacity of each face is added to the collective opacity of all the face under it, sometimes with many faces in the same location the overlay becomes completely opaque, making it difficult to see what is going on.

[image]

Is it possible to disable this so only the outline is visible, or limit the opacity to a fixed amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your *User preferences* and under *Themes* for the *UV/Image Editor* category, lower the alpha of *Face Selected* to suit your needs. At *0*, only the outlines should still show.

[image]

It is also worth noting that there is another option for *Face* color in the same category, the default color for this is white and the default alpha is ~`0.3`.
Therefore, if you have *alot* of faces overlaying each other, this can lead to a white look as it *will* add up so you can also adjust the alpha value there as well depending on what you need. Setting both *Face* and *Face Selected* alpha values to `0` should suffice.

[image]